# use vba to save to a non existing text file using a "save-as" style dialog box

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, vba

I have a macro that outputs to a text file.

What I want is a "save" type dialog box that allows me get the path of an as yet non existent file, by bringing up a file explorer dialogue box.

What I have managed so far is a prompt that requires you to type the file name with full path (not ideal), or to save to an existing file using an "open" style dialog box.

Example code below.

```
Sub UseOpenDialog()
    Dim DestFile As String

    ' Open the file dialog
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .Filters.Clear
        .Filters.Add "Text File", "*.txt"
        .Filters.Add "All Files", "*.*"

        If .Show = True Then
            DestFile = .SelectedItems(1)
            dosomething (DestFile)
        Else: MsgBox "nothing selected"
        End If

    End With
End Sub

Sub TypeFullPath()
    Dim DestFile As String

    DestFile = InputBox("Enter the destination filename" _
     & Chr(10) & "(with complete path):", "Title")
    dosomething (DestFile)
End Sub

Sub dosomething(x)

    MsgBox x

End Sub
```

Comment: Over on StackOverflow: [How can I use the common Save As dialog from VBScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4386124/how-can-i-use-the-common-save-as-dialog-from-vbscript)  Short answer appears to be "You can't since XP - Make your own". :)

Comment: Same info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4619956/vbs-script-works-on-xp-32-bit-but-not-on-7-64-bit

Comment: that's surprising... and a real pain in the behind.  thanks anyway

Comment: I guess a workaround would be to use "open folder" and then prompt to type in a file name.

Comment: I think I've found a solution.  Maybe I'm missing something everyone else isn't but this seems exactly right.  Only works for excel (not other uses of vba) but that's fine.  Will post below

Answer (score 0):

Found this after some searching

Excel has "Application.GetSaveAsFilename" which returns the a string of the full path of a file using a save as style box, or FALSE if the prompt is exited.

Implementation for saving to a text file, with appropriate prompts.

```
Sub saveas()
    Dim Destfile As Variant
saveas::     'bring up saveas dialogue with filters
        Destfile = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(title:="Export", _
            fileFilter:= _
            "Text Files (*.txt; *.csv), *.txt;*.csv," & _
            "All Files (*.*),*.*")

        'exit sub with message if no file selected
        If Destfile = False Then
            MsgBox "no file selected"
            Exit Sub

        'prompt user for overwrite confirmation
        ElseIf Dir(Destfile) <> "" Then
            If MsgBox("Overwrite " & Dir(Destfile) & "?", vbYesNo) = vbNo Then GoTo saveas
        'beware of velociraptors
        End If

    dosomething (Destfile)

End Sub
```